# Path independence of complex integral

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm working through my Complex Analysis notes independently (because of lockdown mode) and I've stumbled across something I don't completely understand. It says here that complex functions $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ which have a primitive $F: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ such that $F'(z) = f(z)$ are path independent if the endpoints remain constant, which makes sense. As a counter-example, it gives $f(z)=f(x+iy)=x$, which is shown not to be path independent. However, $F(x+iy)=\frac{x^2}{2}$ seems to me like a perfectly fine primitive function. Where do I go wrong?

Comment: Does the *complex* derivative of $\frac{x^2}{2}$ exist?

Comment: Only in $(0,0)$ right? And we require existence over a domain containing the paths. Do I understand this right?

Comment: I think that's right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existence of a primitive means existence of an **analytic** function $F$ such that $F'(z)=f(z)$ for all $z$. (The derivative is in the complex analytic sense). $F(x)=\frac {x^{2}} 2$ is not differentiable in this sense.